# VBA find and replace variables inside a for each loop?

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a CSV with 27,000 records with some last names having brackets and text in them such as Harvey (MD5), i've managed to work it so it will do it when targeted at a single cell to delete the text inside the brackets and the brackets themselves but when i try to loop it i get a [RUNTIME ERROR 5] -invalid procedure call or argument....

This is my loop

```
    Sub test()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim myCell As Range
Dim myRange As Range
Dim cellvalue As String

Set myRange = Range("D1:D27168")


For Each myCell In myRange

cellvalue = myCell.Value

openingParen = InStr(cellvalue, "(")
closingParen = InStr(cellvalue, ")")
enclosedValue = Mid(cellvalue, openingParen + 1, closingParen - openingParen - 1)

         Cells.Find(What:=enclosedValue, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    ActiveCell.Replace What:=enclosedValue, Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

Next myCell
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

is there something I'm doing wrong, i've removed the bracket find and replace code to keep it short.

feel like something is a miss

Answer (score 0):

You probably get the error because of `openingParen` and `closingParen` values. If `Mid` gets wrong integer inputs (such as  `Mid("text", 1, 1 - 3)` or `Mid("text", -10, 5)`) it fails with an error 5.
What I recommend is to test your InStr results before calling `Mid` and/or add [Error Handling](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/141571), something like (pseudo-code, not tested) :

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 0
(.....)
On Error Resume Next
newRes = Mid("mytext", iFrom, iTo)
If (Err.Number = 0) Then
  'do what you planned here
Else
  'handle error
  Call MsgBox(Err.Message & CStr(iFrom) & ", " & CStr(iTo))
End If
(...)
On Error Goto 0 'turn off error sinking
```